# if we have 5 different array how to merge them in single array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have 5 different array whose structure is :-

```
Array ( [0] => http://www.php.net/200
)
Array ( [0] => http://www.php.net/?setbeta=1&beta=1302
) 
Array ( [0] => http://www.php.net/downloads.php200
) 
Array ( [0] => http://www.php.net/docs.php200
)
Array ( [0] => http://www.php.net/FAQ.php302
)
```

I need to merge these all in a single array whose structure would be like:-

```
Array ( [0] => http://www.php.net/200

        [1] => http://www.php.net/?setbeta=1&beta=1302

        [2] => http://www.php.net/downloads.php200

        [3] => http://www.php.net/docs.php200

        [4] => http://www.php.net/FAQ.php302
    )
```

One thing i want to confirm that these arrays are forming inside a loop function and it could be of any number and also they have a single name i.e $array

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us how this happens in your code: _"Actually i am getting these array by a single name i.e $array now how could i use array_merge"_? Would be helpful in conjuring up an example for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_merge`.

```
$arr = array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3,$arr4,$arr5);
```

**Edit** After seeing your comment, you are having multidimensional array.

```
$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $old_arr; $i++) {
    $arr[] = $old_arr[$i][0];
}
```

Comment: Actually i am getting these array by a single name inside a function and this arrays could be 7 or 8 or more so now how could i merge them??

Answer (score 3):

Simplest is probably just [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$merged = array_merge( $ar1, $ar2, $ar3, $ar4, $ar5 );
```

Comment: Actually i am getting these array by a single name i.e $array now how could i use array_merge

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
    $arr1=Array ( 0 => 'http://www.php.net/200');
    $arr2=Array( 0 => 'http://www.php.net/?setbeta=1&beta=1302');
    $arr3=Array( 0 => 'http://www.php.net/downloads.php200');

    $merged=array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);

    print_r($merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarray = array();

while ( is_array( array_get_function_here() ) )
{
    $newarray = array_merge( $newarray, $array );
}
```

I would try that if you get the different arrays in a looping function.

The above `$array` is something that `array_get_function_here()` should return for the `while` loop validity check (if it returns and array, the while check runs as `true`). `array_get_function_here()` is just an example and should be some function that returns a value for `$array`.

Comment: 'array_get_function_here()' what does it mean

Comment: Sorry I was a bit vague there. That function should be the function that returns each `$array` for use in the code. While that function returns something that `is_array` sees as `true`, you continue to merge the `$array` members to the `$newarray`.